# onActivityResult byte[] data returning null no matter how large the image

Tags: java, android, null, arrays

I am trying to pass a byte array between activities using `startActivity` and `onActivityResult`. The byte array is null when returning to `onActivityResult` and I cannot figure out why. This happens no matter how large the byte array is so I don't think it has to do with size. Also, I am passing a byte array of approximately the same size using intents successfully in another area. The code:

In post activity:

```
public void callCropperIntent() {
         /* call the cropper to crop a photo from the gallery */
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cropper.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_GALLERY_PICTURE);
    }
```

In cropper activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    File croppedImageFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "test.jpg");
    try {
        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_PICTURE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

            /** When the user is done picking a picture, we'll start the CropImage Activity,
             *  setting the output image file and size to 640 X 640 pixels square.
             */

            Uri croppedImage = Uri.fromFile(croppedImageFile);
            CropImageIntentBuilder cropImage = new CropImageIntentBuilder(640, 640, croppedImage);
            cropImage.setSourceImage(data.getData());
            cropImage.setOutputQuality(100);
            startActivityForResult(cropImage.getIntent(this), REQUEST_CROP_PICTURE);
        }
        else if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CROP_PICTURE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
            /* when we are done cropping, send it back to PostActivity */
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(croppedImageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(croppedImageFile.getAbsolutePath());

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

            //this set bitmap works so I know the bitmap is valid
            //test
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            byte[] imageData = stream.toByteArray();
            //bmp.recycle();

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("image", imageData);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Back in post activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    byte[] croppedData;

    /* check the request code */
    if (requestCode == CROP_GALLERY_PICTURE) {
        /* ensure the request was successful */
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            /* The user picked and cropped a photo */

            /* retrieve photo from cropping activity */
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            croppedData = data.getByteArrayExtra("image");

            /* bytes ready to be sent to pg. 2 of posting process */
            callPostActivityPg2Intent(croppedData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u checked it on another phone???

Comment: Yes, I checked it on a HTC phone and a Samsung Tab 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the cropper class,before finish() you should create a new instance of Intent class instead of obtaining one by calling getintent().

Ex: Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra ()....

Comment: Perfect! I don't know why I didn't think of that.